# Finding the location of ones in a bit mask - Julia

Tags: binary, julia, bitmask

I have a series of values that are each being stored as `UInt16`.  Each of these numbers represents a bitmask - these numbers are commands that have been sent to a microprocessor telling it which pins to set high or low.  I would like to parse this arrow of commands to find out which pins were being set high each time in such a way that is easier to analyse later.

Consider the example value `0x3c00`, which in decimal is `15360` and in binary is `0011110000000000`.  Currently I have the following function

```
function read_message(hex_rep)
    return findall.(x -> x .== '1',bitstring(hex_rep))
end
```

Which gets called on every element of the array of `UInt16`.  Is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Tip: you can write `==(1)` instead of `x -> x == 1`! Also, consider using `digits(hex_rep, base=2)` instead of `bitstring`.
I’d do `17 .- findall(digits(hex_rep, base=2) .== 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach probably depends on how you want to handle vectors of hex-values. But here's an approach for processing a single hex which is much faster than the one in the OP:

```
 function readmsg(x::UInt16)
    N = count_ones(x)
    inds = Vector{Int}(undef, N)
    if N == 0
        return inds
    end
    k = trailing_zeros(x)
    x >>= k + 1
    i = N - 1
    inds[N] = n = 16 - k
    while i >= 1
        (x, r) = divrem(x, 0x2)
        n -= 1
        if r == 1
            inds[i] = n
            i -= 1
        end
    end
    return inds
end
```

Comment: Thanks - this is great.  To handle the vector of hex-values I'm simply going to apply this function element wise - `readmsg.(vector)` .

Comment: That's one possibility, though then you will get a vector of vectors. Is that what you need? If you need a single vector with the locations of the positive bits along the entire message vector, something like @phipsgabler's answer provides that.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest padding your vector into a `Vector{UInt64}` and use that to manually construct a `BitVector`.  The following should mostly work (even for input element types other than `UInt16`), but I haven't taken into account specific endianness you might want to respect:

```
julia> function read_messages(msgs)
           bytes = reinterpret(UInt8, msgs)
           N = length(bytes)
           nchunks, remaining = divrem(N, sizeof(UInt64))
           padded_bytes = zeros(UInt8, sizeof(UInt64) * cld(N, sizeof(UInt64)))
           copyto!(padded_bytes, bytes)
           b = BitVector(undef, N * 8)
           b.chunks = reinterpret(UInt64, padded_bytes)
           return b
       end
read_messages (generic function with 1 method)

julia> msgs
2-element Vector{UInt16}:
 0x3c00
 0x8000

julia> read_messages(msgs)
32-element BitVector:
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 ⋮
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1


julia> read_messages(msgs) |> findall
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 11
 12
 13
 14
 32

julia> bitstring.(msgs)
2-element Vector{String}:
 "0011110000000000"
 "1000000000000000"
```

(Getting rid of the unnecessary allocation of the `undef` bit vector would require some black magic, I belive.)

Comment: You can replace `b = BitVector(undef, N * 8)` with an empty vector: `b = BitVector(undef, 0)`, and then just update `b.len` along with `b.chunks`.

Comment: Ah, right! I was more thinking of `eval` with `:new`...